# Использование SELECT в WITH

Tags: postgresql, select, sql

Читаю мануал по PostgreSQL, дохожу до [использования SELECT в WITH](http://postgresql.ru.net/manual/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-SELECT) и перестаю понимать, как оно работает. Хотелось бы более разжеванного объяснения, чем в мануале:

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(n) AS (
    VALUES (1)
  UNION ALL
    SELECT n+1 FROM t WHERE n < 100
)
SELECT sum(n) FROM t;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
VALUES (1) = это начало рекурсии
UNION ALL
SELECT n+1 FROM t WHERE n < 100 = продолжение рекурсии
```

Получается, в начале таблица 
имеет значение 1,
далее происходит выбор из нее же и добавление результата.
**WHERE n<100 - есть ограничение рекурсии.**
По сути своей WITH 
создает виртуальную таблицу в памяти (это сведения из документации по SQL SERVER).